# Regex select string between any html tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need to be able to get all content between **any html** tag.
Currently I am using:

```
var result = data.match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g).map(function(val){
 // validate
}
```

The closest I have got is: `<[a-z1-9]{1,10}>(.*?)<\/[a-z1-9]{1,10}>`

However looking at a [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/jR7wZ3/1), it is not correct.

It's not closing on matching tags and is even missing some out, what am I missing?

My aim is to get anything between all tags **not** between a certain two.

https://regex101.com/r/jR7wZ3/1

Comment: Maybe [DOM approach is safer](https://jsfiddle.net/uncysdv4/1/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract an HTML tag name from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975162/extract-an-html-tag-name-from-a-string)

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/833146

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @WiktorStribiżew

```
var el = document.createElement( 'faketag' );
el.innerHTML = txt;
var arr = [];
[].forEach.call(el.childNodes, function(v,i,a) {
        arr.push(v.innerHTML);
});
console.log(arr);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uncysdv4/1/