# How to configure stylelint to ban all HTML tags

Tags: html, stylelint

Is there a way to configure [stylelint](https://stylelint.io/) to disallow all selectors which include tag names?

I found the (stylelint-selector-tag-no-without-class)[https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-selector-tag-no-without-class] plugin, using which I want to ban ALL tag names, present and future, without listing each and every tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`selector-max-type` rule](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/selector-max-type/) to disallow all selectors which include tag names (aka [*type selectors*](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#type-selectors)):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "selector-max-type": 0
  }
}
```

This will disallow all tag names, present and future, as the rule disallows selectors that are parsed as type selectors, rather than relying on some list of known type selectors.

Comment: You may want to ignore compound selectors like `p.class-name`. `"selector-max-type": [0, {"ignore": ["compounded"] }]`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: @jeddy3's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68521250/915875) is better. Use that.**

Configure the rule like so for all tags and custom elements: ​`"plugin/selector-tag-no-without-class": ["/\\w+/"]`.

If you use BEM you'll want to allow `__` and `--` prefixes too: `"plugin/selector-tag-no-without-class": ["/^(?!.__*).\\w+/"]`.

*(Solution based on these SO answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28975388/915875 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/1240365/915875).*